# react-router v6 extending search params instead of replacing it

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Currently, doing `setSearchParams(/* an object */)` will replace the existing search params. If I would like to extend the search params instead of replacing them, e.g. adding a new param. What will be the most elegant way to achieve that?

I know I can modify the `searchParams` directly, then do something like `setSearchParams(newSearchParamsToObject)`. Yet, since `searchParams` is not an object but a `URLSearchParams`. The code will be long and ugly.

Edit: Since some one appears don't understand what I have posted

Currently if we do something like this:

```
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams({ a: 1 });
setSearchParams({ b: 2 });
```

It will replace the `searchParams` with `?b=2`.

What I would like to achieve is adding `b=2` to existing search params, i.e. the final search params should be `?a=1&b=2`.

Answer (score 50):

I suppose it would/should be trivial to set the search param value you want to add.

```
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

...

searchParams.set(newParamKey, newParamValue);
setSearchParams(searchParams);
```

[image: Edit react-router-v6-extending-search-params-instead-of-replacing-it]

```
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

const clickHandler = () => {
  searchParams.set("b", 2);
  setSearchParams(searchParams);
};

...

<button type="button" onClick={clickHandler}>
  Add "b=2" param
</button>
```

Introduced in `react-router@6.4` the `setSearchParams` now also takes a function, similar to the `useState` hook, to access the previous query params object to update from.

```
setSearchParams(searchParams => {
  searchParams.set("b", 3);
  return searchParams;
});
```

This is handy if you are using the `setSearchParams` in a `useEffect` hook as you won't need to list the current `searchParams` object as an external dependency.

Comment: `setSearchParams([...searchParams.entries(), ['b', 2]]);` it will append the value and you will end up with ?b=2?b=2?b2 (if for example you change the paramas pressing a button for example)

Comment: @claudiu Ack, you're totally right. It works once the first time, but it will keep appending duplicate query params upon subsequent calls. Thanks for the heads up, I should have tested better.

Comment: I wonder if this code, searchParams.set(name, value); setSearchParams(searchParams);, mutates searchParams before setting it. What implications could this have? We were taught not to mutate objects.

Comment: @IgorSukharev It *would* mutate the `searchParams` object. The implication would be that the updated `searchParams` value would be available within the closing scope. This is likely the impetus for introducing the "updater function" API so it works similarly to the React `useState` updater syntax.

Answer (score 6):

I was just doing something similar and this is what I found out.

As mentioned above, you can use `searchParams.set`, but also `searchParams.append`. The difference is, when using `append`, it will add new search param, even when it has the same name.

So for given search params `?a=123&b=456`:

```js
setSearchParams((prevParams) => {
  prevParams.append('b', "789");
});

// output -> "?a=123&b=456&b=789"
```

but if you use `set` the result is overwritten

```js
setSearchParams((prevParams) => {
  prevParams.append('b', "789");
});

// output -> "?a=123&b=789"
```

But if you have more search params and you don't want to repeat `set` or `append` for each, you can use object spread with combination of `entries()` and `Object.entries()`

```js
const newSearchParams = {
  a: 111,
  c: 000,
};

setSearchParams((prevParams) => {
  return new URLSearchParams({
    ...Object.fromEntries(prevParams.entries()),
    ...newSearchParams,
  });
});

// output -> "?a=111&b=456&c=000"
```

Answer (score 2):

Router v6 solution here (don't know if works with previous version too): `setSearchParams` accept a function that should return new search params, **actually giving you the previous value**:

For example:

```js
setSearchParams(prev => ([...prev.entries(), ['foo', 'bar']]);
```

This is basically like @Drew Reese answer, but using the previous "state", like you would do with `useState` from React.

Comment: I tried your solution and if the param already exists it will keep appending it appending e.g.: `?foo=bar&foo=bar`

Answer (score 2):

This version ->

```
setSearchParams(
    prev => ([...prev.entries(), ['foo', 'bar']])
);
```

will add the same param without replacing, like this ->

```
?s=5&p=0&p=1
```

param `p` was added the second time, instead of `?s=5&p=1`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [URLSearchParams.append(name, value)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/append) method, in case you want several 'b'.

```
setSearchParams(searchParams.append('b', 2));
```

It's not like your modifying the state, here. You're just manipulating an URLSearchParams object. You don't have to worry about mutating it.

Comment: Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'URLSearchParamsInit'.

Answer (score 0):

React Router v6 have the `useSearchParams()` method that return an array that has, as a first value, a way to get the actual search params, and as a second, a method to set new values, the return value type definition is this: `[URLSearchParams, SetURLSearchParams]` and you can find more on the [official documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params).

You can see a full working example to solve your problem on [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-playground-forked-xyvuie?file=/index.js:0-1381).

And this is a wrap up:

```
import React, { useCallback, useMemo } from "react";
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

function getRandomNumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
}

function getAllParamsFromEntries(searchParamsEntity) {
  const finalValues = {};
  const entries = searchParamsEntity.entries();
  let isDone = false;

  while (!isDone) {
    const iteratorElement = entries.next();
    if (iteratorElement.value) {
      finalValues[iteratorElement.value[0]] = iteratorElement.value[1];
    }
    isDone = iteratorElement.done;
  }

  return finalValues;
}

const MainScreen = () => {
  const [searchParamsEntity, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const allSearchParams = useMemo(() => {
    return getAllParamsFromEntries(searchParamsEntity);
  }, [searchParamsEntity]);

  console.log(allSearchParams);

  const appendRandomSearchParam = useCallback(() => {
    setSearchParams((previousParams) => {
      const searchParams = getAllParamsFromEntries(previousParams);
      return {
        ...searchParams,
        [`randomParam${getRandomNumber()}`]: getRandomNumber()
      };
    });
  }, [setSearchParams]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Search params now: {JSON.stringify(allSearchParams, undefined, 2)}</p>
      <button onClick={appendRandomSearchParam}>Append</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

We can manipulate `searchParams` as normal object and its values as arrays.

Adding query param. **This works as append.**

```
const addTag = (tag) => {
  setSearchParams((prev) => {
    return {tags: [...prev.getAll('tags'), tag]};
  });
}
```

Result

```
?tag=one
?tag=one&tag=two
```

Now if we want to **delete some query param** from this array.

```
const deleteTag = (tag) => {
  const includesTag = searchParams.getAll('tags').includes(tag);
  setSearchParams(prev => {
    if (includesTag) {
      const updatedTags = prev.getAll('tags').filter((el) => el !== tag);
      return { tags: updatedTags };
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
const patchSearchParams = (newParams = {}) => {
  setSearchParams((searchParams) => {
    const prevParams = {};
    searchParams.forEach((value, key) => {
      prevParams[key] = value;
    });
    return { ...prevParams, ...newParams };
  });
};
```